# nginx + fastCGI stops servering php after a couple of refreshes

Tags: php, codeigniter, nginx, fastcgi

I setup a new CentOS server with nginx and fastCGI. I followed this linode article to get everything installed and configured http://library.linode.com/lemp-guides/centos-5/ . It seems to work fine, until I refresh the page a couple times. After 2 refresh nginx just stops serving php and just gives me an error. If I load the php page in a different browser, it will work again, until I fresh. Is there some kind of arbitrary limit on the number of requests a session can make?

I'm new to nginx. I'm much more comfortable with Apache configs. I'm sure it's just something in the nginx.conf. But other than pointing the locations to the directory where my php is, I didn't change any of the default configs in /etc/nginx.conf.

I don't think it matters, but it's running a codeigniter application.

Thanks.

Comment: Does Nginx give you a 5xx error? If so, it's an issue with PHP, not Nginx.

Comment: Yes it was a 50x error. I tweaked some conf settings like worker_processes, keepalive_timeout, and added server_names_hash_bucket_size 128; and that seems to have fixed the problem.